# Shift column one row up without consecutive ids

Tags: mysql

I want to shift the values of val by one row up. The examples if find use and ID that gets one bigger for the next value. Which is not the case in my data. Other examples that come close look for the neirest value, but i want to to have the closest higher value, so i can shift the val data one up. The MySQL version i use is 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

The problem with the example shift below is that i dont know how to set table a equal to table b:

```
SELECT a.id, a.value, IFNULL(b.value, 'inf') shiftedValue
FROM a as a LEFT JOIN a as b ON a.id = b.id - 1
```

Table:

```
  ID|val|
    --|---|
     1|  1|
     5|  2|
     6|  2|
     9|  3|
    13|  4|
    15|  4|
    20|  3|
```

Resulting table

```
  ID|val|
    --|---|
     1|  2|
     5|  2|
     6|  3|
     9|  4|
    13|  4|
    15|  3|
    20|  null|
```

Comment: Sorry my data was not saved correctly, i updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
LEFT JOIN test t3 ON t1.id < t3.id AND t3.id < t2.id
SET t1.val = t2.val
WHERE t3.id IS NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1ae6b8581f59aed9e4557145fb2eeb38